# What is the MassTransit pattern for retrieving RabbitMQ password from a dependency?

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

Using MassTransit.RabbitMq 8.0.9, in a .Net Core 3.1 project using AspNetCore 3.1.10 and IServiceContainer.  The password for RabbitMq is stored in a secrets vault, accessible from a dependency-injected interface.  All of the examples I've been able to find just get the password from configuration.

I'd like to do something like

```
var secrets = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISecretRetrieval>();
var rabbitPassword = secrets.GetRabbitMqPassword();
```

and then hand that password to `IRabbitHostConfigurator`, but inside `UseMassTransit...UseRabbitMq`, there isn't an `IServiceProvider` instance that I've seen.
Alternatively, I could create a configuration object with a constructor-injected dependency on `ISecreteRetrieval`.  I see examples for `IConfiguration<MassTransitHostOptions>` that show how to create and register my own class with its own constructor dependencies.   Can I do that with `IConfiguration<RabbitMqHostSettings>` even though `RabbitMqHostSettings` is an interface, not a class like `MassTransitHostOptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `UsingRabbitMq` block, the first parameter is a service provider.

```cs
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
{
    var secrets = context.GetRequiredService<ISecretRetrieval>();

    cfg.Host("hostname", h =>
    {
        h.Password(secrets.GetRabbitMqPassword());
    });
});
```